# Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'access_token' in package 'com.example.'

Tags: android

While trying to add Mapbox basic map to my Android Application I found this error:

```
Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'access_token' in package 'com.example.vlad.myfirstglapp'
Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'access_token' in package 'com.example.vlad.myfirstglapp'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command 'C:\Users\Vlad\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'
finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

This what I've added to built.gradle

```
 repositories {
  mavenCentral()
 }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    // add the Mapbox SDK dependency below
    compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:2.1.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

And here is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** Create a mapView and give it some properties */
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setStyleUrl(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS);
        mapView.setCenterCoordinate(new LatLng(41.885, -87.679));
        mapView.setZoomLevel(11);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       mapView.onStart();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
      mapView.onStop();
   }

    @Override
    public void onPause()  {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
   }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
         super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
         mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote? This is an actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with mapbox SDK as a workaround you can in activity's onCreate set the key manually

`mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
//put this directly after findViewById
mapView.setAccessToken(getString(R.string.accessToken));`

and remove

`mapbox:access_token=""` from the AndroidManifest.xml

This works for me